# innerHTML to input value

Tags: javascript, html

The following codes reflect the data from the map as html I want to use the information from input value How can I do this?

```
document.getElementById('location').innerHTML = place.formatted_address;
document.getElementById('lat').innerHTML = place.geometry.location.lat();
document.getElementById('lon').innerHTML = place.geometry.location.lng();
```

```html
<ul id="geoData">
    <li>Location: <span id="location"></span></li>
    <li>Latitude: <span id="lat"></span></li>
    <li>Longitude: <span id="lon"></span></li>
</ul>
```

I want to get these codes as input value but I couldn't do it my javascript knowledge is a bit bad

I tried these codes but didn't

```
document.getElementById('location').value = place.formatted_address;
document.getElementById('lat').value = place.geometry.location.lat();
document.getElementById('lon').value = place.geometry.location.lng();
```

```html
<input type="hidden" name="adres" id="location" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="lat" id="lat" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="lon" id="lon" value="">
```

Comment: IDs have to be unique on the page for your code to work properly. Your inputs have the same IDs as your spans.

Comment: @thmsdnnr the above codes are the default codes. The code below is my experiment

Comment: @admcfajn I have already done the same thing above but the value does not change the value of this problem ..

Comment: How are you verifying that the value does not change?

Comment: [Does your JavaScript come after the `<input>`s?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element)

Comment: It can be a possibility that the javascript cannot find ```place.geometry.location.lat()``` and therefore is returning ```undefined``` .

Comment: [link](http://www.expertphp.in/article/autocomplete-search-address-form-using-google-map-and-get-data-into-form-example) I've solved my problem with the source here thanks